# Change from J2000 to Apparent or Of Date position

Tags: astronomy

I am trying to change from J2000 to Apparent positions. Astronomical Algorithms by Jean Meeus addresses but does not give a correct answer. VSOP87 gives the Apparent or Of Date positions in VSOP87C and VSOP87D but I need to calculate directly from J2000. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you looked into the [SOFA library](http://www.iausofa.org/) (maintained by the International Astronomical Union)? They have some routines in C and fortran for converting from [ICRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Celestial_Reference_System) (solar system barycentric RA,Dec, pretty close to J2000) to CIRS (earth centric RA,Dec) and even to apparent RA,Dec for a given observer taking into consideration atmospheric effects. I've used this in my own C++ ephemeris library ([CppEphem](https://github.com/Jvinniec/CppEphem)) and it seems pretty accurate.

Comment: In the VSOP87 paper, Bretagnon & Francou did give the rotation matrix that transform VSOP87A to VSOP87C... If you don't have the paper, I can email you... it is a small pdf file...

Comment: I would like to see the pdf if you may.

Comment: Here is the link: http://huycan.com/download/vsop87_equations.pdf